# Compare ranges in different sheets; sheets keep changing; how can i cope with that?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this macro which compares two ranges from two sheets with each other an it works. 
Every week a new version of this worksheet comes available and i want to compare that to the latest version. So now I compare Sofon2 with Sofon (New vs Old). 
My idea is to fill in the name of the old sheet in A1 in another sheet and the name of the new sheet in B1. Does anyone know how to do that or have a better solution?
thank you

```
Sub Compare()

Call compareSheets("Sofon", "Sofon2")

End Sub


Sub compareSheets(Sofon As String, Sofontest As String)

Dim mycell As range
Dim mydiffs As Integer

For Each mycell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Sofontest).range("M:M")
    If Not mycell.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Sofon).Cells(mycell.Row,     mycell.Column).Value Then

        mycell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
        mydiffs = mydiffs + 1

    End If
Next

MsgBox mydiffs & " differences found in Column M (Salesman)", vbInformation

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sofontest).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Store names of workbook isnt a big deal, but can you clarify how sheet names will be generated? Or will they be in some current directory? or something to catch up?

Comment: If you have sheet names in a cell, you can pass the cells values as the arguments of compareSheets.
Something along the lines of, call compareSheets(Range("A1").value, Range("B1").value).